# When to use DJISDKManagerDelegate. componentConnectedWithKey or productConnected?

Tags: dji-sdk

I am wondering about what the difference in when and how to access a component after a product connected.

One can either wait until

- `DJISDKManagerDelegate.productConnected` and `productChanged` get called and then access the component

or wait for

- `DJISDKManagerDelegate.componentConnectedWithKey` gets called, check for the key and then get the component from the product.

Can I safely assume, that when a product connected, all its components are connected as well?

Are there any advantages or disadvantages of any of the both methods above? Maybe different use cases?

Comment: similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64354240/difference-between-dji-onproductchange-and-onproductconnect

Comment: Basically you need to listen to both component and product connected events. Unfortunately just because the product is connected it does not mean that the individual components, such as the flight controller, camera etc are connected. You will need to implement onComponentChange and add a listener to detect when a component is connected. These don't always connect in the same order and may start to connect before or after the product is connected.

Comment: Thank you @BrienCrean, that confirms my assumption that components might connect at a later point after product connection and not immediately after. Anyways, finished next chapter of tutorial series https://twissmueller.medium.com/programming-dji-drones-part-3-3529b43b461